# Interpolation with matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a vector with different values.
Some of the values are zeros and sometimes they even come one after another.
I need to plot this vector against another vector with the same size but I can't have zeros in it.
What is the best way I can do some kind of interpolation to my vector and how do I do it?
I tried to read about interpolation in mat-lab but I didn't understand good enough to implement it.
If it's possible to explain it to me step by step I will be grateful since I'm new with this program.

Thanks

Comment: I dont get this: do you want to replace zeros or are there vectors of different lengths?

Comment: I want to replace the zeros with other values but in a smart way so when i will do my plot it will be close to what it was supposed to be.

Comment: but interpolation can give you zeros as well...

Comment: what if you would just skip zero-values?

Comment: If you are going to interpolate a vector containing zeros, and especially one after another, it will be very likely for the interpolation to entail zeros as well. Maybe you could explain why you want to do this a bit more?

Comment: I can't skip them, my vector is inside a matrix and i need to keep the size of my matrix.

Comment: if it is just for plotting reasons, you can skip the values for sure! do you need it later on or just for plotting?

Comment: I have a matrix and the number of rows is the number of places in witch i calculated the intensity of my video. The number of columns is the number of frames in my video. The values inside my matrix are the mean intensities in the area i watched. i want to do a plot for each place i watched (the number of plots will be the number of rows). Since it's in a matrix i need to keep the size of the matrix and i can't just skip the zeros. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Maayan be careful with interpolation! see my comment below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from a dataset consisting of two equal length vectors `x`,`y`, where `y` values equal to zero are to be excluded, first pick the subset excluding zeros:

```
incld = y~=0;
```

Then you interpolate over that subset:

```
yn = interp1(x(incld),y(incld),x);
```

Example result, plotting `x` against `y` (green) and `x` against `yn` (red):

[image]

*edit*

Notice that, by the definition of interpolation, if terminal points are zero, you will have to take care of that separately, for instance by running the following before the lines above:

```
if y(1)==0, y(1) = y(find(y~=0,1,'first'))/2; end
if y(end)==0, y(end) = y(find(y~=0,1,'last'))/2; end
```

*edit #2*

And this is the 2D version of the above, where arrays `X` and `Y` are coordinates corresponding to the entries in 2D array `Z`:

```
[nr nc]=size(Z);
[X Y] = meshgrid([1:nc],[1:nr]);
X2 = X;
Y2 = Y;
Z2 = Z;
excld = Z==0;
X2(excld) = [];
Y2(excld) = [];
Z2(excld) = [];
ZN = griddata(X2,Y2,Z2,X,Y);
```

`ZN` contains the interpolated points.

In the figure below, zeros are shown by dark blue patches. Left is before interpolation, right is after:
[image]

Comment: one should mention, that this manipulates the data in a very heavy way. if this is some measurement of intensity, it could give you a completely wrong result! instead of interpolating one should set zero to close to zero. But well, this is the solution that the OP was asking for...

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus I agree that generally speaking it is bad practice to throw away data because one "doesn't like it". In the OPs case it seems the sampling was sparse and missing entries were just filled with zeros. How one interpolates becomes a rather important question.