# Matlab surf only points, not lines

Tags: matlab

I have to draw a hipsometric map on a 3D plot. I have two vectors `1x401` (named `xLabels` and `yLabels) which are the geo coordinates, and`401x401`(named`A`) matrix with the altitude data. To plot the data I use:

```
surf(xLabels, yLabels,A,'EdgeColor','None','Marker','.');
```

which leads to something like that:

[image: bad picture]

But i would like to have something like that:

[image: how it should look like]

On the second image, only the surface is plotted, while my image looks like pillars.

I tried even make my vectors to `401x401` using `meshgrid` but it did not have any effect.

Do you have any idea what I should change?

@EDIT

I checked for X and Y data. I quess is too small interval (0.0083), but when i try plot good second of upper plots with same interval it draws correctly.

@EDIT2:

```
sizeX = 4800;
sizeY = 6000;
pixdegree = 0.0083; % 1 pixel is 0.0083 degree on map
intSize = 2;
lon = 37 + (35/60);
lat = 55+ (45/60);
fDEM = 'E020N90';
fHDR = 'E020N90.HDR';
[startXY, endXY] = calcFirstPixel(lon, lat); %calc borders for my area
f = fopen('E020N90.DEM');
offset = (startXY(1,2)*sizeX*intSize)+(startXY(1,1)*intSize);
fseek(f, offset,0); %seek from curr file pos
x = 0;
A = [];
BB = [];
jump = (intSize*sizeX)-(401*2);
while x<401
    row = fread(f, 802);
    fseek(f, jump, 0); %jump 2 next row
    A = [A row];
    x = x+1;
end
fclose(f);
A = A';
A = A(:,2:2:802);
m1 = min(A(:)); %wartość minimalna dla naszej podziałki
m2 = max(A(:)); %wartość maksymalna dla naszej podziałki
step = m2/8; % będzie 8 kolorów
highScale = m1:step:m2-step; %wartości graniczne dla każdego z nich
%handles.axes1 = A;
colormap(hObject, jet(8));
startXtick = 20 + pixdegree*startXY(1,1);
endXtick = 20 + pixdegree*endXY(1,1);
startYtick = 90 - pixdegree*endXY(1,2);
endYtick = 90 - pixdegree*startXY(1,2);
[XX,YY] = ndgrid(startXtick:pixdegree:endXtick,startYtick:pixdegree:endYtick);
xLabels = startXtick:pixdegree:endXtick;
yLabels = startYtick:pixdegree:endYtick;
surf(xLabels, yLabels,A,'EdgeColor','None','Marker','.');
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
grid on;
view([45 45])
```

And [.DEM files](http://galaxy.eti.pg.gda.pl/katedry/ksg/dydaktyka/Techniki_obliczeniowe_w_systemach_geoprzestrzennych//Materialy/e020n90.zip)

```
function [startXY, endXY] = calcFirstPixel(lon,lat)
    global fHDR;

    format = '%s %s';
    f = fopen(fHDR);
    cont = textscan(f, format);
    LonStart = str2double(cont{1,2}{11,1});
    LatStart = str2double(cont{1,2}{12,1}); 
    diffPerPix = str2double(cont{1,2}{13,1});
    fclose(f);
    x = LonStart;
    countX = 0
    y = LatStart;
    countY= 0;
    while x<lon
        x=x+diffPerPix
        countX = countX +1;
    end
    while y>lat
        y=y-diffPerPix
        countY = countY+1;
    end
    startXY= [countX-200 countY-200];
    endXY = [countX+200 countY+200];
end
```

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008237/matlab-surf-meshgrid-issue-2-vectors-1-matrix-surface-plot?rq=1). I have the feeling this will solve your problem.

Comment: Looks like you have a bunch of values which are zeroes - maybe you want to filter them out? Also 401x401 is a lot of points, which is probably why you chose not to plot the edges. If you want to check the smoothness of your data, maybe try just plotting a smaller section (e.g. `surf(xLabels(1:30), yLabels(1:30), A(1:30, 1:30));`).

Comment: can you show as the result of @BrianL code ?

Comment: [Result](http://imgur.com/WF3Nczr) of @BrianL code.

Sorry, but i have too low reputation to paste image directly.

Comment: @Matt it didnt help me. Using `ndgrid` do not help.

Comment: It just looks like its yout data that is like that

Comment: I just did a small test in Matlab. Your way of calling surf and the arguments are ok! Maybe your data is just like that... You can try the first proposition from @BrianL and post the results. Therefore you have to interpolate the zero-elements! How this is done can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715639/interpolation-with-matlab) (2d-version using `griddata`). But it is important to know _why_ those are zero. Maybe they are out of bounds (up/down) so an interpolation will not represent the original data. If they are just missing data points, an interpolation should be ok.

Comment: I have idea, but i don't know matlab function - can i resample or something that? I mean for each  `2x2` matrix in my `A` i calc mean value and put it in new matrix. Is in matlab any function which is does it ?

@Matt It is correctly values. All data are presentation of altitude of Moscow region readed from `.DEM` file.

Comment: If a zero-entry is just a point without a measurement, interpolation is the way to go in my opinion. Could you edit your post to show how the data is being read exactly? If the dem-file's license allows, you could post a link to it as well.

Comment: @Matt All what u want is in post. 

I tried interpolation. It seems quite ok, but looks to angular in my opinion.

Comment: There are parts of the code missing.

Comment: Now is all what You need. I left setters for sliders value.

Comment: `calcFirstPixel` or it's result would be of interest as well...